# TypeError: decoding str is not supported, when encoding is explicitly specified

Tags: python, python-3.x

Any idea why this is happening when encoding is explicitly specified?

```
In [23]: import sys

In [24]: sys.getdefaultencoding()
Out[24]: 'utf-8'

In [25]: str(b'', encoding='utf-8') == ''
Out[25]: True

In [26]: str('') == ''
Out[26]: True

In [27]: str('', encoding='utf-8') == ''
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-e187972042f8> in <module>()
----> 1 str('', encoding='utf-8') == ''

TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

According to the docs of `str`:

> encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding()

Comment: You seem to think that `str('')` decodes using the default encoding. It doesn't. It doesn't decode at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help is pretty clear here:

> `str(object='') -> str`
>
> `str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str`
>
> Create a new string object from the given object. If encoding or
>   errors is specified, then the object must expose a data buffer
>   that will be decoded using the given encoding and error handler.
>   Otherwise, returns the result of object.**str**() (if defined)
>   or repr(object).
>   encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding().
>   errors defaults to 'strict'.

You can specify the encoding only for bytes (b`''`) not for strings such as  `''`.